# Using submodules with local repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules

Does anyone have any tip for me regarding the following issue:

- I have some local repositories ABC which i use in a project X.
- I added these repositories ABC as submodules to project X.

However, when i push my project X, the files inside the submodules are not pushed to the remote bare repository on my ssh server (I only see empty directories). How can i achieve this while keeping the repositories ABC local.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is really possible.  When you push to your remote repo, git will be pushing the information about your submodules (i.e. the info that is in the `.gitmodules` files), but it will not push the submodules' files themselves.  This would be true whether it is a bare repo or not, and is kind of the point of submodules.  A submodule is something that is in a separate repo and all you keep in your super project is a reference to it.

I'm pretty sure that if the files are separated out into submodules, and you want them available on the server, you'll need to have remote repos on the server for these submodules.  If you start tracking the ABC files in your super project, then they are no longer really submodules.

You could maybe set up a hook to just *copy* your ABC files over to your server after a push, however they will of course not be part of your remote repository, just available on your remote server.

In summary though, just set up a remote repo for them if you have to have them up there.